# update `link_to` helper when clicked; Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

In a view.html.erb, I want to use something like:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= book.title %></td>
        <td><%= book.author %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', book, class: 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book), class: 'btn btn-default' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Reserve it', books_path(book, :situation_id => 2), class: "btn btn-mini btn-success" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

When I click on the button "Reserve it", I would like that the field "situation_id" of this book become equal to 2.

How can I do that?

Comment: not sure but onclick(); might help you. like you can try pushing the value of situation_id=2 using javascript then. have you tried doing this way already?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Abhinay. I didn't tried to do like you say. How do you do it? I'm sorry i'm a beginner in rails and a beginner in English (sorry).

Comment: Since you are new, something for you to read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648 . try to write title of your question in short yet informative.

Answer (score 0):

If a book has a situation association (and your associations are set up correctly), then you could pass it as a parameter with <%= link_to 'Reserve it', books_path(book, :situation_id => book.situation_id), ... %>

However, you shouldn't need to pass it the situation_id param since you can just grab it with the book instance variable that you're going to. In other words you can do

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id]).include(:situation)
end
```

and your book will load up the situation as well and it will be available in your book show view.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. Sounds like OP wants to set the book's situation_id to 2 once the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, i would like to change the book's situation_id to 2 (before was set to 1) when i click on the button. Situation_id is already associated correctly to Book. I don't succeed to do that. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Not a Rails solution but I hope this will help you thinking in right direction may be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
$("a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + 'books/?situation_id=2';
});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" id="link" >hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```